# Portion of view not lloaded properly by jQuery .load()

Tags: php, jquery, fat-free-framework

I'm working inside Fat-Free-Framework, using the [F3 Template Language](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/views-and-templates), but I've come across an issue I'm not sure how to solve.

I've got a portion of a webpage, which contains data from a database that needs to be updated at some interval to make sure the person looking at the page is looking at up-to-date information.

I can easily load the data this way:

```
<div id="container">
    <include href="module/views/table_pending.htm"/>
</div>
```

This works, but it doesn't update at an interval. I know I need to use jQuery for this, so I tried to use the `load()` method to load this page fraction, but it isn't rendering properly.

This is my Javascript

```
function loadPageContents() {
    $('#container').load('{{@BASE}}/app/modules/module/views/table_pending.htm');
}
loadPageContents();
```

Here is a minimal version of my `table_pending.htm`:

```
<repeat group="{{ @data }}" value="{{ @device }}">
    {{ @device[uid] }}<br>
</repeat>
```

When using F3's `include` element, my page renders as expected:

[image]

But when using jQuery `.load()`, it seems that F3's template language isn't really parsed at all (thus variables not being replaced, loop not working properly etc):

So my question is, how can I include this page fragment into my main page, update it on an interval, and still render my template language?

[image]

Comment: did you mean `loadPageConents` ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg yeah but the function name is basically irrelevant

Comment: Not sure how F3 works, but looks like it's a php templating system, so it has to be executed server side. And that looks like if the jQuery is grabing the template fragment directly. There's no model to pull data from. That template has to be invoked though a controller.

Comment: @msg Your comment helped me solve my issue, I just made a new route to generate the structure I need, and then `load()` that new route.